# How to call a method on a ListView which has an abstract type

Tags: java, listview, abstract

I get an error in the `getNodes()` method. ***

```
    The method getfilter(ListView<CellObject>) in the type NodeUtil is not 
applicable for the arguments (ListView<Index>)
```

But since `Index` implements `CellObject`, and `Employee` extends `Index`, it should work?

```
public abstract class Index implements CellObject {

}
```

..

```
@FXML private ListView <Index> listView;

public List<Node> getNodes() {
     List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
     ***nodes.add(NodeUtil.getfilter(listView));***
     return nodes;
 }


public class Employee extends Index {
    @Override
    public String getInfo() {
        return name + address;
    }

}


public abstract class NodeUtil {
    public static List <Node> getfilter(ListView <CellObject> lv) {
         ...
         lv.getItems().stream()
            .filter(c -> c.getInfo().contains("xxx"))
             ...
    }

}
```

Comment: I think it's something like `ListView<? extends  CellObject>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In generics you have to specify if you want a specific type or a type that `extends` certain type, use this :

```
    public static List <Node> getfilter(ListView < ?  extends CellObject > lv) {
```